# asp:Button how to capture Response.WriteLine

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using the OnClick of the asp:Button tag to compute a report which I would like to display as an innerHTML of a div tag.  I would like to use the Response.WriteLine method to return this html file.  Does ASP.NET webforms provide a way of capturing this response?

Am I forced to use JavaScript instead?  I am using C# on the Server side.

Comment: Why `Response.WriteLine`? that's silly. There's no need to write directly to the response. Just assign the generated HTML to the div using the controls provided to you.

Comment: What do you suggest?  What causes the page to refresh?

Comment: The button click causes the page to initiate a postback. If you don't want that, you'll need to learn about AJAX and similar techniques. Do you have a choice in what platform you use? Web Forms is an old, archaic piece of junk. If you're learning for the first time, I suggest you learn [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc) or how to combine client side frameworks (such as Angular) with server side endpoints (such as [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Forms way of doing this is to use a control and set its InnerHTML from the code behind. Here's a self contained example:

```
<%@Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">    
    protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reportHTML = "<p>This is a <span style='font-weight: bold;'>report!</span></p>";
        ReportDiv.InnerHtml = reportHTML;
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="GenerateReport" Text="Generate Report" />
            <div runat="server" id="ReportDiv"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```